# Print a list from my class (python)

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary

I have a class with information about customers. One of all the data elements is `self.history` were I save the history for every customer in a list. Every customer is also in a dictionary outside the Class were I have saved the name as key, and other information as values. My question is how do I print this list for every customer.

i have tried:

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self, name, car, reg):
        self.name = name
        self.car = car
        self.reg = reg
        self.history = []


def add_new_customer:
    account = dict()
    name = input("Name: ")
    car = input("Car: ")
    reg = input("Regnummber : ")
    account[name] = Customer(name, car, reg)


def print_all_accounts():
    for keys in account:
        print(keys.history)
```

the code is bigger and I do a lot of things like
`name.history.append()` and so on (500 lines). But this is the thing that doesn't work.

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'history'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're just looping over the dictionary keys.

```
for keys in account:
    print(account[keys].history)
```

or even better:

```
for key, value in account.items():
    print(value.history)
```